# Split a list by value of its dataframe

Tags: r, list

Assuming that we have this data (we only have the list **"Acc"**) :

```
rdate <- function(x,min = paste0(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-01-01'),
                  max = paste0(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-12-31'),
                  sort = TRUE)
  {dates <- sample(seq(as.Date(min), as.Date(max), by = "day"), x, replace = TRUE)
  if (sort == TRUE) {sort(dates)}
                  else {dates}}

X <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10000, sd = 0.8),
                B = sample( LETTERS[1:24], 10000, replace=TRUE),
                C = rdate(10000))
Acc <- split(X,X$C,drop = TRUE)
```

So, we have a list divided by one data frame per date. We need to have **two lists**, one with data frames before 06/01 (the date doesn't really matter here) and the other one with data frames from 06/01 to 12/31.

Is there a simple way to do it with R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a cutpoint (`x`) and subset your list (`Acc`)

```
x <- as.Date("2018-06-01")
# data frames before 06/01
Acc1 <- Acc[names(Acc) < x] # Acc1 has 151 data frames
# data frames from 06/01 to 12/31
Acc2 <- Acc[names(Acc) >= x] # Acc2 has 214 data frames
```